# How to test android application on Circle CI with Google Services Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, git, circleci

I'm developing android application with Google Services Gradle Plugin(It is needed from Firebase), and the plugin needs google-services.json.

I think the json file should not be under the control of git because it have some values that should be concealed(ex. api_key), but Circle CI needs the one.

If google-services.json can look up environment variables, the problem can solve.(values are concealed on git repository and Circle CI can get values from environment variables).
But, I can't find mechanism of look up environment variables from google-services.json.

I have three questions.

1) Should google-services.json really be ignored from VCS?
2) Does Google Services Gradle Plugin have the mechanism of look up environment variables from google-services.json?
3) Is there other ways of refer google-services.json from Circle CI?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) Yes, it should - it contains sensitive information like your API key.

2) I don't think so

3) You can use similar aproach as in https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/google-auth/

- encode your google-services.json in base64. Make sure to remove any spaces from the encoded string
- put this to Environment Variable in Project settings of Circle CI ( I named it GOOGLE_SERVICES)
- in your circle.yml decode this variable to google-services.json file in your app directory. In my case I use

  `echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES | base64 --decode > ~/${HOME}/app/google-services.json`

Comment: `echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES | base64 -di > app/google-services.json` worked for me

Comment: I fixed the link.